# Copy an ssm path with other name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, ssm

We keep environment information (endpoints, passwords,etcs) under an ssm tree, lets call it /qa/ and we'd like to find a simple way to copy it over to /qa01/ /qa02/ etcs, and in the process modify some variables.

We have dumped the current content with:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path  --path "/qa/"
```

to a file but I can not find a way to modify and upload it under a new path.

The idea being we will set environment variables using

```
chamber export qa --fortmat=dotenv > .env
```

at build time and

```
chamber exec qa -- node server
```

at runtime under ECS.

Is it a good way to keep environment information out of git?

Thanks

Comment: After asking my question I came across this blogpost:

https://www.davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2018/07/05/migrating-aws-system-manager-parameter-store-secrets-new-namespace

While crude, it seems to be working.